# Display related rows in same row in MSaccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have a set of related rows which I need to display in a single line. For example, the data I have is in different rows.

```
"ID"   RecordDate   "ExpType"  "OrigBudget"  "ActualCost"   
1001    1-5-2017    Hardware    $ 5000                    
1001    2-6-2017    Hardware                    $ 5200
```

The Original budget is approved at an earlier time for the same record but the Actual cost often differs and is recorded at a later date. I want the output as

```
ProjectID YearofEntry ExpenseType        OrgBudget  ActualCost  <BR>
 1001          2017       Hardware        $ 5000     $ 5200       <BR>
```

I have tried group query to aggregate it based on ExpenseType and ProjectId but not successful in getting it into a single row so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT ID,
       Year([RecordDate]) AS YEARofEntry,
       ExpType,
       Sum(OrigBudget) AS SumOfOrigBudget,
       Sum(ActualCost) AS SumOfActualCost
FROM youtable
GROUP BY ID,
         Year([RecordDate]),
         ExpType;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you always just have two rows for each ExpType - one with the original budget and one with the actual costs - you could simply use a `GROUP BY`:

```
    SELECT ID               AS ProjectID
          ,YEAR(RecordDate) AS YearofEntry
          ,ExpType          AS ExpenseType
          ,MAX(OrigBudget)  AS OrgBudget
          ,MAX(ActualCost)  AS ActualCost
      FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY ID
          ,YEAR(RecordDate)
          ,ExpType
```

Comment: Thanks Esteban, I used SumOf instead of Max but it did the trick